# How unique is each row based on 3-4 columns?

Tags: python, r, dataframe, bigdata, unique

I am going to merge two datasets soon by 3 columns.
The hope is that there are no/few 3 column group repeats in the original dataset. I would like to produce something that says approximately how unique each row is. Like maybe some kind of frequency plot (might not work as I have a very large dataset), maybe a table that displays the average frequency for each .5million rows or something like that.

Is there a way to determine how unique each row is compared to the other rows?

```
1   2   3
A   100 B
A   200 B
A   200 B
```

Like for the above data frame, I would like to say that each row is unique

```
1    2    3
A    200  B
A    200  B
A    100  B
```

For this data set, rows 1 and 2 are not unique. I don't want to drop one, but I am hoping to quantify/weight the amount of non-unique rows.

The problem is my dataframe is 14,000,000 lines long, so I need to think of a way I can show how unique each row is on a set this big.

Comment: Are you using pandas or just built-in functions for Python?

Comment: 14,000,000 is a lot, but maybe not too much. I would try to push all of that into a `collections.Counter` and see how it performs.

Comment: *"show unique"* and *"show how unique"* are two different things, though the second is a bit harder (memory-wise) than the first. Of your examples, you've only demonstrated "identical" but not "similar". Also, you've tagged both [tag:python] and [tag:r], are you looking for either language here? It might be helpful to have some clarity/guidance there.

Comment: Either language. I mean identical, I don't care about similar. When I merge the two datasets to add a fourth column, I would like for the fourth column to be completely unique (ideally). If it is not completely unique, that is fine I don't want to drop columns, but I am preparing an estimate for someone else. I tagged both languages because I can use either

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using pandas, here's one possible way:

```
import pandas as pd

# Setup, which you can probably skip since you already have the data.
cols = ["1", "2", "3"]
rows = [
        ["A", 200, "B",],
        ["A", 200, "B",],
        ["A", 100, "B",],
        ]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=cols)

# Get focus column values before adding a new column.
key_columns = df1.columns.values.tolist()

# Add a line column
df1["line"] = 1

# Set new column to cumulative sum of line values.
df1["match_count"] = df1.groupby(key_columns )['line'].apply(lambda x: x.cumsum())

# Drop line column.
df1.drop("line", axis=1, inplace=True)
```

## Print results

print(df1)

Output -

```
   1    2  3  match_count
0  A  200  B            1
1  A  200  B            2
2  A  100  B            1
```

Return only unique rows:

```
# We only want results where the count is less than 2,
# because we have our key columns saved, we can just return those
# and not worry about 'match_count'
df_unique = df1.loc[df1["match_count"] < 2, key_columns]

print(df_unique)
```

Output -

```
   1    2  3
0  A  200  B
2  A  100  B
```